# How to fetch data from core data by Date as a section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
 fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath:"time", cacheName: nil)
```

**I am using this code where time is the column name that stores Date() object.**

I want to get section base on Date 
e.g..

> 29-11-2016 total row = 3
>
> 28-11-2016 total row = 1
>
> but currently getting separate section for each time difference on
>   same date.

**So, how can i achieve this using fetch request controller. ????**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't use hours, minutes and seconds.. better you can store as a `date` (For ex: 29-11-2016) in `core data`. Then your data will group based on date.

Comment: you mean store only Date not time right???

Comment: Yes, exactly correct.

Comment: I tried to do like save string date as "29-NOV-2016" string It give actual result like 

29-11-2016 total row = 3

28-11-2016 total row = 1

but not shorting according to date wise.

Comment: is there any clue how to get sections based on date???

Answer (score 0):

This problem have already solution in stack overflow. It will work please check it.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

    var orders = [Order]()
    var startDate : NSDate = NSDate()
    var endDate : NSDate = NSDate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchedResultController.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        fetchData()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects!.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let order = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![section] as! Order
        return ((order.products?.count ?? 0) + (order.services?.count ?? 0))
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let textCellIdentifier = "ExampleTableViewCell"
        let row = indexPath.row

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExampleTableViewCell

        let order = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.section] as! Order // Data fetched using NSFetchedResultsController
        let products = (order.products?.allObjects ?? [Product]()) as! [Product] // Swift Array
        let services = (order.services?.allObjects ?? [Service]()) as! [Service] // Swift Array

        if (row < products.count) { // this is a Product row
            cell.orderLabel.text = products[row].name!
        } else { // this is a Service row
            cell.orderLabel.text = services[row-products.count].name!
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let order = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![section] as! Order
        return "\(order.date)"
    }


    func orderFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Order")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate, endDate) // startDate and endData are defined elsewhere

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        return fetchRequest
    }

    func fetchData() {
        let fetchRequest = orderFetchRequest()
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath:nil, cacheName: nil)

        do {
            try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

I just copy and paste it. Hope it will work for you. If Not then i will help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but above code is for fetch results between two dates. but my question is how to fetch date wise section for each date a group of result. means date will be section and result will be number of row for each date.